# Why $10^{a+b}= 10^{a}.10^{b}$ is considered isomorphism from addition to multiplication operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

One algebraic structure is isomorphic to another if there is an isomorphism from the first to the second.

The two algebraic structures of concern are :
$(\mathbb{R'}, +), (\mathbb{R'}, *), \mathbb{R'}= \mathbb{R}-\{0\}
$, the operation $10 $ to the power $a+b$ turns addition into multiplication.

To show they are isomorphic algebraic structures, the function must be a bijection between the underlying sets.

This needs equal elements in both sets, as well as bijective mapping.
But, still even if same base is there, it is not clear how Isomorphism is achieved.
Is it by showing linearity of mapping from one algebraic system to another, that can show?

The same question with map from $(\mathbb{R'},*)$ to $(\mathbb{R'},+)$ exists for $\ln(ab)= \ln(a)+\ln(b)$.

Comment: There is a typo there, where $(\mathbb R,*)$ should be  $(\mathbb R^\times,*)$, where $\mathbb R^\times:=\mathbb R\backslash\{0\}$. Also that "To show they are isomorphic structures, need equal elements in both sets" best be replaced with the "To show the function is an isomorphism, the function must be a bijection between the underlying sets."

Comment: Typos aside, do you know what is an isomorphism=bijective homomorphism between two groups? Especially the term "homomorphism"?

Comment: @Sampah yes, homomorphism is a bijective map between two sets

Comment: @jiten Linearity has nothing to do with this. We are dealing with isomorphism of groups, not of linear spaces.

Comment: @jiten A homomorphism is not a bijective map. It is merely a map that preserves the relevant structure on the sets.

Comment: @NDewolf what is the relevant structure here?

Comment: As @Miguel said, you should look at them as groups, not vector spaces.

Comment: @jiten It also depends on the definition of power you are using. If we take your title for granted, this is exactly the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism) of isomorphism.

Comment: @Miguel can you please elaborate, am not clear about "definition of power".

Comment: @jiten How do you define $10^x$ for $x$ real?

Comment: @Miguel  sorry for unavoidable delay. $10^x=10^a+10^b$, for $x=a.b$. say, $x=2.3$, then $$10^{2.3}=10^2∗10^{0.3}=100∗1.99526=199.526.$$ For that need logarithms. Say, $$10^{\frac{1}{10}}= 1.2589.$$

Comment: @Miguel so you mean as logarithms are not a linear function, so $10^{a+b}$ also is not a linear function, hence linearity does not work here.

Comment: @jiten My advice is to start over. You are trying a theoretical and abstract exercise, so you have to be very rigorous and write explicitly all definitions. The point is that $10^\pi$ for instance is not so easy to define as $10^{2.3}$ because $2.3=\frac{23}{10}$ is rational.

Comment: @Miguel for irrational power of $10$, request details. Might be structure of solution is apparent then to me.